# How to give more than one labels with an image in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to implememt multitask Neural Network in tensorflow, for which I need my input as:

> **[image label1 label2]**

which I can give to the neural network for training.

My question is, how can I associate more than one label with image in TFRecord file?

I currently was using **build_image_data.py** file of inception model for genertrating TFRecord file but in that cases there is just one label per image.

Answer (score 1):

Do they have always two labels? If so try "label1-label2" as one label. 
Or simply build two networks, one for label 1 and the other for label 2.

Are they hierarchical labels? Then, check out Hierarchical classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

1. I got this working. For any one looking for reference, you can modify Example proto of build_image_data.py file and associate it with two labels. :)